# Why can't I use the sudo command with this user?

Tags: linux, centos, sudo, centos-7

I am not a system engineer (I am more a software developer). I have the following problem trying to deploy an application on a Linux Centos system.

As the first operation, I need to install Java and perform some preliminary checks installing some tools. During this preliminary phase I performed this command:

```
sudo yum install redhat-lsb-core
```

I obtained an error like this one:

```
USERNAME is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported
```

So I suspect that this user is not a root user or it is not allowed into the **/etc/sudoers** file. Is it? What can I check to ensure this suspect?

Using this user I also tried to do:

```
cat /etc/sudoers
```

and I obtained:

```
cat: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
```

Performing:

```
grep 'x:0:' /etc/passwd
```

I obtained:

```
webadmin@webadmin.spaccount.it [~]# grep 'x:0:' /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

So I think that there is only a root user that is not the one that I am using.

So do you think that the only solution is to ask the person handling this server to give me permission to execute `sudo` command?

Comment: you need to edit `/etc/sudoers` using a proper user with admin rights, so `su cat /etc/sudoers` and/or `su nano -w /etc/sudoers` to edit it and add the user. Until they are properly added you will have to use `su` and enter the root password to get access.

Comment: Your user doesn't need to get *into* the `sudoers` file, that's the job of the `sudo` tool and the error you get says `USERNAME is not in the sudoers file` so it *can* read the file but your user isn't in there. You need to get your user in there first.

Answer (score 1):

### If you are not in the `/etc/sudoers` file, then you cannot run commands as `sudo`.

#### That said, if you are a software developer and not in the `/etc/sudoers` file, just let the server admin install the packages you need installed.

Your question is really an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/243319); you seem to not need `sudo` access as much as you want to install `redhat-lsb-core`.

Knowing that, it might be better if you just ask the person who is `root` on the server to run:

```
 yum install redhat-lsb-core
```

As you state clearly in your question:

> “I am not a system engineer (I am more a software developer).”

Unless you know what you are doing as far as `root`/`sudo` access on a server goes and *truly* need the `sudo` access, it might be best you just let that stuff be handled by the people who know how to deal with `root` processes on that server.

But as for the specifics of `sudo` access, the `root` user needs to assign you as a `sudoer` in `/etc/sudoers`.

Nothing else has to be done. Basic users are not in the `/etc/sudoers` by default for obvious reasons: If everyone was placed in the `/etc/sudoers` file, then they would all just be the equivalent of `root` so what is the benefit?

Answer (score 0):

The owner of the system (the one that has access to root) must give you permission to do tasks as root. `sudo` is a root-delegation tool. The root can delegate specific tasks to a user, or give general root access to a user (or group for that matter).

If a normal user would be able to give himself root permissions, that would be a huge security issue. That is the reason why `/etc/sudoers` is only editable by root. Oh, and use `visudo` rather than editing  that file directly.